# Ubuntu 16.04 login screen password field loses style

Tags: 16.04, gui

I have done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 twice, and eventually, I start up the machine and the login password field has turned white and plain. I haven't noticed any correlation between my activity on the system nor any system problems. In case it is relevant, both installs are on VirtualBox machines. Why does this occur and how do I fix it, or what steps can I take to debug it? It isn't a critical issue, but my curiosity grows every time I log in with this ugly password field.

Here's a picture of how it used to look and how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/03/restore-default-login-screen-ubuntu-14-04/   Check if this works.

Comment: @luv.preet It didn't help, but I did discover something interesting. My lock screen is correct (looks like the top image). Your article gave me good information to google and I've discovered that the greeter can be different for the login and lock screens. So, maybe I'm heading in the right direction toward figuring this out.

Comment: please tell me the solution once you get it

Comment: As one would expect, updating to 16.10 fixed it, but that's not really a fix so much as just reinstalling everything. I thought I tried to reinstalling the relevant desktop packages, but perhaps I didn't do that right. I bet the solution is either, reinstalling the right packages, resetting their configurations, or removing some conflicting package. Unfortunately, I don't have the issue anymore to test it, but perhaps it will break again even on 16.10.